# IsAlpha function not accepting my input

Tags: c++, string

So the purpose of the isalpha function is that it only accepts letters(a-z) but that doesn't seem to be the case for my code. If I input the letter p, the error message is displayed. If input a word like "city", the error message is still displayed. What's wrong with my code.

So because of the use of cin instead of cin.getline, the second piece of code works but the first one constantly loops the error message no matter what. Can someone please explain?

Note1: If you're are thinking that I should just use the cin operator instead of the cin.getline, well then that creates a new problem. You see, this program is part of another program and in that program, all of my input streams(>>) have been cin.getline. So, if I use both use cin then cin.getline, it's going to create conflict. I've tried to use cin.ignore but to no avail. Regardless, I still don't know why this is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int SIZE = 10;
char letter[SIZE];

cout << "Enter a word. ";
cin.getline(letter, SIZE, '\n');

while(!isalpha(letter[SIZE]))
{
    cerr << "Error, only letters are allowed. ";
    cin.getline(letter, SIZE, '\n');
}

cout << "This is acceptable. ";

return 0;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int SIZE = 10;
char letter[SIZE];

cout << "Enter a word. ";
cin >> letter[SIZE];

while(!isalpha(letter[SIZE]))
{
    cerr << "Error, only letters are allowed. ";
    cin >> letter[SIZE];
}

cout << "This is acceptable. ";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure `letter[SIZE]` does what you think it does.

Comment: Well why does it work for cin but not cin.getline? That's all I want to know.

Comment: `cin >> letter[SIZE];` is undefined behaviour. `cin.getline(letter, SIZE, '\n');` is not. The condition following both is undefined behaviour anyway, so neither actually works.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What do you mean by neither actually work. The second piece actually accomplishes what it's meant to do. If I enter the word party in the second program, the result that I get is "This is acceptable". In the first piece of code, the error message keeps on repeating. So you see, the second piece of code actually does works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because letter[SIZE] is considered as a pointer pointing to the first element of your array. So  your while(!isalpha(letter[SIZE])) is only checking if the first character is alphanumeric or not.

Here's an example for a better understanding;

Try and print letter[SIZE] on the screen.

```
int main()
{
const int SIZE = 10;
char letter[SIZE];

cout << "Enter a word. ";
cin >> letter[SIZE];

cout << letter[SIZE] // this will only output the first character that the user entered.

cout << "This is acceptable. ";

return 0;
}
```

so if you want to check the entire word they entered, you will need to loop through element by element.